# Is there a way in Excel to split a large file into a series of smaller ones, based on the columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sheet called say detail_data.xls now i want to split this sheet based on columns say column a,j and s in one sheet called chasis.
column c, f and r in second sheet called port.

like wise

Comment: just use control+click on the columns to select a subset and copy onto a new sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Method A.

Open the spread sheet.  Choose Save As.  Save it as a different name (or in Google Docs, "Make a copy".  Open that new copy.  Delete the columns you do not want.  Save and close.  Open the original.  Delete the columns that would enable you to make this a different sheet.

In other words... you have excel sheet detail_data.xls.  It has 6 columns... a through f.  You wish to move a, c, and d to a new sheet.  Create a copy of the spread sheet.  On the new sheet, delete b, e, and F.  On the old sheet, delete a, c, and d.  You now have a new sheet with just the columns you wanted.

Method B.

Select and copy the columns you want on a new sheet.  Open new sheet.  Paste columns into new sheet.

**EDIT** Unless you read this and you realize that you didn't explain what you really wanted to do, or that you explained it incorrectly...